# Why does profiles defined with modules are executed first -maven?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-profiles

I have case where i want to download the jar and unpack the jar.
Within that jar i need to invoke the pom.xml from particular location ,
For eg: I downloaded jar and unpacked at

```
/home/sohanb/admin/target/com/tooling/admin/dockerfiles/cfg
```

Now at,
**/home/sohanb/admin/target/com/tooling/admin/dockerfiles/cfg** there is **pom.xml** which i need to call to build my docker image.

To do this i thought of doing something like this as below,

I have profiles where i want to invoke it sequentially.

1. unpack-jar
2. build-tools

Some how my modules profile is always getting called. I am not sure why this is happening or it is default nature of maven to invoke modules profile first.

Here is sample pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>smp</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>dockerize</name>
<description>docker image creation</description>
<dependencies>
</dependencies>
<properties />

<profiles>
<profile>
        <id>unpack_jar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>unpack</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>unpack</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com.sigma.samp</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>tooling.sigmaadmin</artifactId>
                                        <version>6.0.0-20160405.213109-41</version>
                                        <type>jar</type>
                                        <excludes>**/*.class</excludes>
                                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>                   
            </plugins>
        </build>                
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>build_tools</id>                
            <modules>
            <module>target/com/tooling/admin/dockerfiles/cfg</module>
            <module>target/com/tooling/admin/dockerfiles/logs</module>
            </modules>
    </profile>          
</profiles>
```

```
mvn install -Punpack_jar -Pbuild_tools
```

when i execute above command, it always calls the modules profiles giving error,

```
[ERROR] Child module .... does not exist @
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Why are you referencing modules if they do not exist?

Comment: modules will be found one my unpack-jar profile is be called

Comment: Issue i am facing why profile sequence is not handled by maven?

Comment: Maven is not the problem here. What are you defining two profiles? And yes, Maven will try to compile the modules first because that's what modules are. They are intended to be built first. What is the _real_ problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Maven is correctly invoking your profiles, but profiles are not invoked in sequence, they are activated on the maven build and then the new/crafted build is executed. In your case you are unpacking artifacts (in prepare-package phase, too late but even during the first phase, the validate phase, would probably not help) then pretend maven would later on build this new modules, while maven would try to build modules as first step since the activated profile will add them since the beginning

Comment: Ok , i understand that. I have case where i need to explode the downloaded jar and invoke the pom.xml in it. You can see the path in module where my pom.xml falls after unpacking the jar.
can there be way to do this?

Comment: That still looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us more about your use-case.

Comment: see the updates with more specific use case